# row open on onclick event which is initially hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, show-hide

I want to open a row on onclick event when the particular link is clicked. For that i having number of row where each row below having a hidden row, when i click a row just below row will display.

**CODE:**

```
<script>
            function toggle(number) {
                alert("toggle function called"+number);
                var simNum = number;
                if (document.getElementById(simNum).style.display = 'none') {
                    document.getElementById(${dList.simNumber}).style.display = '';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById(${dList.simNumber}).style.display = 'none';
                }
            }

        </script>
<tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>${dList.deviceAccount}</td>
                    <td>${dList.vehicleId}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" onclick="toggle(${dList.simNumber});">${dList.simNumber}</a></td>
                    <td>${dList.imeiNumber}</td>
                    <td>${dList.lastTimestamp}</td>
                    <td>${dList.lastLoginTime}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="${dList.simNumber}" style="display: none;">
                    <td align="center" colspan="7">
                        Expiration Time:<input id="read" type="text" value="${dList.expirationTime}"/>
                        <input type="button" value="Edit"><input type="button" value="Save">
                    </td>                
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript code

```
 function toggle(number) {
                alert("toggle function called"+number);
                var simNum = number;
                if (document.getElementById(simNum).style.display = 'none') {
                    document.getElementById(simNum).style.display = '';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById(simNum).style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
```